# Glassfish 3 update tool (pkg) doesn't install : Not in GZIP format

Tags: glassfish-3

I am running java 6 on windows. I just installed glassfish 3.1.2.2 using exe and chose not to install a domain during the installation. Then I tried running the pgk tool, and found out I had to install it. At first it didn't work, due to a 404. I found an answer here http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18884) to that problem (have to edit cfg_cache). Then I tried running it again, but now I am seeing this:

Input/output error: Not in GZIP format

Here is the complete output.

C:\opt\glassfish3\bin> .\updatetool

The software needed for this command (updatetool) is not installed.

If you choose to install Update Tool, your system will be automatically
configured to periodically check for software updates. If you would like
to configure the tool to not check for updates, you can override the
default behavior via the tool's Preferences facility.

When this tool interacts with package repositories, some system information
such as your system's IP address and operating system type and version
is sent to the repository server. For more information please see:

http://wikis.oracle.com/display/updatecenter/UsageMetricsUC2

Once installation is complete you may re-run this command.

Would you like to install Update Tool now (y/n): y

C:\opt\glassfish3\bin>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java" -Dimage.path="C:\opt\glassfish3\bin\.." -jar "C:\opt\glassfish3\bin\..\pkg/lib/pkg-bootstrap.jar" "C:\Users\NEUMEI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pkg-bootstrap5312.props"
Proxy: Using system proxy settings.
Install image: C:\opt\glassfish3
Installing pkg packages.
Downloading 2 packages.
Downloading pkg (514 files, 6,463,109 bytes).
File 514/514
Downloading python2.4-minimal (278 files, 3,828,949 bytes).
File 278/278
Executing 906 install actions.
Input/output error: Not in GZIP format

Could not download application packages. This could be because:
- a proxy server is needed to access the internet. Please ensure that
the system proxy server settings in your Internet Options control panel
(under Connections:LAN Settings) are correct, or set the HTTP_PROXY
environment variable to the full URL of the proxy server.
- the package server or network connection is slow.
If you are getting time out errors you can try setting the
PKG_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT and PKG_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT
environment variables and try again. For example to increase
the timeouts to 300 seconds set them to 300
- the package server is down or otherwise inaccessible or it is
generating invalid data. Please contact the provider of the package
server.